# Async and Await in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

So I am trying to get my head wrapped around the `async` and `await` in C#, I have read a bunch, seen a few questions here on SO, but I am just not quite sure yet.

So I have written a little sample in hopes you can help me to understand a little clearer what is happening and when to use it. Hopefully my sample is correct.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new MyClass();
        c.AccessTheWeb("http://www.google.com");

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public async Task AccessTheWeb(string url)
    {
        var result = await GetUrl(url);

        Console.Write(result);
    }

    public async Task<string> GetUrl(string url)
    {
        string result;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        }

        return "Did async task";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question that you can ask in English instead of C#?

Comment: @EdS. Seemed pretty straight forward to me. I provided a sample snippet and asked if someone could explain exactly what was happening as the code ran.

Comment: @Eds. how come you don't understand a question written in proper C#? `KindOfDevelopers.FirstOrDefault(x => You.Are(x))`??

Comment: I suppose... but what don't you understand exactly?  There are a ton of resources out there, as well as the official documentation.  Do you just want someone to explain it to you?

Comment: Yeah, just having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Comment: @Sam when you use `await ...`, the compiler creates a state machine which "resumes" execution of your method body (retaining context) *after* the asynchronous call to the awaitable has completed.

Comment: @Sam I found it helpful to learn how the `yield` keyword works first

Comment: @Sam, with all respect, but you didn't ask anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an [+async+ intro on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find useful. It has several followup resources at the end that include tips such as:

- Console `Main` usually use `Wait` on a top-level task.
- Asynchronous methods should end with `Async`.

Answer (score 1):

The program looks Ok to me, I tweaked a few things like waiting for the asynchronous operation to complete. Instead of waiting for user input, I used `.Wait()`

```
class Program
{
    void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new MyClass();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting ...");
    c.AccessTheWeb("http://www.google.com").Wait();

    }

}   
    public class MyClass
    {
        public async Task AccessTheWeb(string url)
        {
            var result = await GetUrl(url);

            Console.Write(result);
        }

        public async Task<string> GetUrl(string url)
        {
            string result;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            }

            return result; // why did you use "Did async task" ?
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used `Did async task` so the output was shorter in the console and I could see the order in which things were happening.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you call an `async` method the execution continues, with the method being executed in another thread, and you can do other things in the meantime.

You most likely want to check later if the method has completed. You can do so by checking the `Task.IsCompleted` or `Task.TaskStatus` properties.

But if for some reason you need to wait for the result of the function before you can move on, you use the `await` keyword before the method call, to ensure that the execution stops and *waits* for the method to complete before moving on. This also tells the compiler that it can take a break from executing this particular thread, because it is doing nothing but waiting.

There's a good [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) about all this.

Comment: -1... " you don't want the asynchronicity, you use the await" - there is not much truth here...  You probably mean something else and clearly some better wording could deserve upvote.

Comment: Is this better? I admit I am not a C# veteran. I think I kind of understand what is going on inside, but I don't want to spread misinformation, so feel free to downvote me if you think my answer is naff.

Comment: (Removed -1). It is indeed better. Also one should `await` in almost all cases to correctly handle errors (search for "C# fire and forget async"), pretty much the only case when it is ok to not `await` the result is UI event handlers in desktop apps...